# Does Google FCM support's HTTP 2 based Apple APNs API?

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

As per new notification from apple before April 1, 2021 all app needs to use HTTP/2 based APIs, as we are using FCM for cloud messaging, need confirmation that firebase services will work fine in the future as well,

> The HTTP/2-based Apple Push Notification service (APNs) provider API
> lets you take advantage of great features, such as authentication with
> a JSON Web Token, improved error messaging, and per-notification
> feedback. If you send push notifications with the legacy binary
> protocol, we strongly recommend upgrading to the APNs provider API.
>
> To give you additional time to prepare, the deadline to upgrade to the
> APNs provider API has been extended to **March 31, 2021**. APNs will
> no longer support the legacy binary protocol after this date.
> https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=c88acm2b

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just received message from Firebase support, no action items required from our end.

> The details about Updated [APNs provider API deadline will](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=c88acm2b) not
> have any performance impact or issues on FCM, and there’s no action
> item needed on your end in relation to [Apple Push Notification
> service server certificate update](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=7gx0a2lp).
>
> Let me know if you have any clarifications.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can you please confirm you are using Firebase Legacy HTTP or HTTP v1 on your backend side to send push notification.

Comment: This is for HTTP v1, for legacy API we will need to confirm.

Comment: @NiravD confirmed by support, legacy APIs will handle that too. Message from support
"There’s no changes needed in your implementation because all the request and handling mechanism is within the FCM server to communicate on the APNs API"

Comment: @prasad Are you 100% sure that legacy protocol will still work with APNS?

Comment: @OlivierBrand this is the reply that I received from Firebase FCM Support, that it will work. If you have any doubts I'll suggest you check with Firebase support, usually, they will reply within 2 working business days.